# return value of prefix and postfix in C++

Tags: c++, prefix-operator, postfix-operator

Why in C++ the prefix return a reference but the postfix return a value?

Comment: Scott Meyers covers this really well in More Effective C++.

Comment: Meaningless as written. I imagine you mean to ask about the pre- and post-increment and decrement operators. Discussed (occasionally at length) in various contexts: Try http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=i%2B%2B+%2B%2Bi+[c%2B%2B to find some existing cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because with prefix you modify the object and then return it (so it can be *lvalue*), and with postfix you return the unchanged object (i.e. a copy) and only then update it (this is of course done by first storing the copy in a temporary, updating the original object, and then returning the temporary by value.)